# Can't save data in RTDB

Tags: java, android, firebase

With this code I'm supposed to be able to retrieve a value directly from a RTDB (realtime database) and show it in the screen of my app,  but nothing happens, app compiles fine. I hope you could help me.

[On the image lays the simple structure of my RTDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2hGu.jpg)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final  String PATH_START = "start";
private static final  String PATH_MESSAGE = "message";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final TextView tvMessage = findViewById(R.id.tvMessage);

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    final DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference(PATH_START)
            .child(PATH_MESSAGE);



    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
               tvMessage.setText(snapshot.getValue(String.class));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "not able to read in Firebase",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });


  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @AlexMamo I have attached in an image the JSON structure of my database. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Is any of the onDataChange or onCancelled even triggered?

Comment: Hi again, it seems that my virtual divece is nos runnig properly I tried the app in another  computer and it runs correctly.